# $f^{p_1}$ belongs to $L^p(E)$ and $g = \chi_{E}$ belongs to $L^q(E)$?

Tags: lp-spaces, holder-inequality

I was reading a Corollary in Royden, which states:
[image: Corollary 3]

In the proof,

[image: Proof]

The book mentioned by observation that $f^{p_1}$ belongs to $L^p(E)$ and $g =  \chi_{E}$ belongs to $L^q(E)$. I am not sure how this fact can be observed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that:
$$||f^{p_1}||^{p}_p = \int\limits_{E} \, |f^{p_1}|^p \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \int\limits_{E} \, |f|^{\frac{p_1 p_2}{p_1}} \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \int\limits_{E} \, |f|^{p_2} \, \mathrm{d} \mu = ||f||^{p}_{p_2} < \infty \Rightarrow f^{p_1} \in L^p(E)$$
Additionally:
$$||\chi_{E}||^{q}_q = \int\limits_{E} \, |\chi_{E}|^q \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \int\limits_{E} \, \chi_{E} \, \mathrm{d} \mu = \mu(E) < \infty \Rightarrow \chi_E \in L^q(E)$$

Comment: Thank you! But for your first line of proof, you seem to be using $|f^{p_1}| = |f|^{p_1}$. I am not sure whether it is true for general?